# Text disappears when frame is moved to first page in document

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I am working on a book someone else created. The first page in the document has what looks like an empty text frame. The text intended for that first page begins on the next page, leaving the first page blank. If I drag the text box off the first page, the text is visible on the pasteboard. When I drag it back on, the text disappears again.

I have already checked for text wrapping: there is none.
I have already checked for other images on other layers: also none.

I also tried adding a new page before the page in question. When I do that, the text sits where it is intended to (so there's a new blank page that appears first, then the now second page and third pages show the text as intended). But when I delete the newly added blank first page, the problem recurs. Is it possible some setting is applied to whatever the first page is?

Comment: I'm afraid this may take direct file examination. It could be something as simple as a forced frame jump in the text.. or not.

Comment: "Type / Show hidden Characters" may help if it is a page break.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is some kind of odd/even issue.

Maybe the firs character an Odd Page Break or the firs paragraph's style defined to start in odd page.